# Make UITextField Placeholder private in didSet

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am subclassing a UITextField to build a textfield in which a user can enter a certain amount of money in a certain currency. I want the placeholder to be get only or be private. Instead you set the currency and the amount you want the placeholder to be. Then the textfield automatically adapts the string, e.g. to a certain number of decimals etc.

The code below stops at:
    placeholder = oldValue

This makes sense because it keeps calling the setter and ends in an infinite loop. I can not find a better way to do this, anybody knows how I could make this work?

Thanks

```
var placeholderAmount: Float = 0{
    didSet{
        self.placeholder = String(self.roundedStringWithAmount(placeholderAmount, to: self.numberOfDecimalPlaces)) + self.currencyString

    }
}

override var placeholder: String?{
    didSet{
        placeholder = oldValue
        print("Placeholder Set to CurrencyTextField. Do not do that")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and be a little less hacky.

```
override var placeholder: String?{
    didSet{
        if placeholder != oldValue {
            placeholder = oldValue
            print("Placeholder Set to CurrencyTextField. Do not do that")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With your answer it seems so obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict the access level of a variable declared in a super class.  It's a bit hacky, but you could just set a flag that allows to not loop infinitely:

```
var ignoreUpdates = false

override var placeholder: String?{
    didSet{
        if !ignoreUpdates {
            ignoreUpdates = true
            placeholder = oldValue
            ignoreUpdates = false
            print("Placeholder Set to CurrencyTextField. Do not do that")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that this might be the only way but I wanted to double check.
I will probably just surrender and leave the possibility to change the placeholder open.

Comment: You could also assume the user will "do the right thing" and try and use an `NSNumberFormatter` to convert the placeholder into a `Float` and store it in your `placeholderAmount` var.